# Scaling images to an area

Tags: math, scaling, image-scaling

I'm trying to scale a bunch of images so that they have the same area, but keep their aspect ratio, but am having trouble find a formula to do so.

Does anyone know a formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given area A,

```
newx * newy = A
newx / newy = oldx / oldy
```

which gives you:

```
newy = A / newx
newy = newx / (oldx / oldy)

A / newx = newx / (oldx / oldy)
A * oldx / oldy = newx ^ 2
```

which then solves to:

```
newx = sqrt(A * oldx / oldy)
newy = A / newx
```

Then again, this is a maths question, not a programming one...

Comment: And what's the problem with that? The only thing that would change is `Math.sqrt`. And it's still a maths question.

Answer (score 3):

Given you have two images with sizes (w1, h1) and (w2, h2) and you want to scale the second image to the same area as the first while maintaining the aspect ratio, then

```
A = w1 * h1
new_w2 = sqrt(A * (w2 / h2))
new_h2 = A / new_w2
```

Comment: I think it should be new_w2 = sqrt(A * (w2 / h2))